# Is iOS tutorial "Your Third iOS App: iCloud" out of date?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm following along through the three tutorials provided by Apple for iOS newbies.  The first two seemed to very closely follow guidelines that, from what I gather, fit the newest enhancements and recommended coding habits for Objective-C, but the third one doesn't seem to.

Not sure if a link will work: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloud101

1. It explicitly tells you to call @synthesize for all the declared properties. Isn't this unnecessary as long as you don't care to customize the backing variable's name?
2. It tells you to make forward declarations of methods. Is this still required by the compiler? When are forward declarations unnecessary?
3. It frequently makes use of instance variables that are accessed directly instead of using properties. Aren't properties the preferred method for data storage? When would it be preferable to avoid using a property? I'm guessing they were doing this as a way to create private variables, maybe. There are no anonymous categories used in this tutorial so maybe those became available after the tutorial was written.

I think there are more. Just want to be sure I'm not missing out on some potential techniques for the tool belt here in my attempt to avoid what may be bad habits in modern Objective-C. The fine print at the end shows that it was updated in April 2013, but maybe they didn't bother to update all the code style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They probably just didn't update the code style. Also, Apple sample code is often quite diverse in its style. Regarding specific questions:

1. This is now generally unnecessary - but in some cases is, for instance, when a class conforms to a property declared in a protocol.
2. Within the same file, methods that are implemented but not declared elsewhere are visible. Generally, declaration of methods in a header is only required when the methods must be called from outside the class.
3. Using instance variables can be a matter of taste I suppose. In `dealloc` and initializers it's often recommended to use ivars directly in case of side effects in the property implementations.

Comment: Regarding (2), can methods be safely passed to other classes as part of a block if they are not declared in the @interface?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I assume you're asking if you have a block literal in a file that has visibility of a method, can you pass it to another object where it will be invoked, even if there isn't visibility in the scope of the code where the block is invoked. Of course, that is totally fine. A block's statement body has the same scope as its declaration. Invoking the block imposes no requirements of knowledge of the block's original scope.

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't need to manually `@synthesize` properties anymore
2. Forward declarations in the implementation file are not needed anymore.
3. Some people like ivars, some people like properties, just make sure you use them consistently.

Comment: By consistently, do you mean to stick to one or the other, or just be careful not to confuse the two?

Comment: I mean stick to one or the other, unless you have a very good reason not to.